# how to add text and images together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitextview

I'm developing a notebook based application. it consists of notes and images also.

I'm unable to find the best way of coding to add images and text together. it is also editable, so I'm getting confused whether to take `scroll-view` or text view. If I take `scroll-view` there is no editable option. if I take text view we can't change frames of the image .

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? could you please decribe a bit further? are you using tableView?

Comment: yes, my requirement is to editable notebook. i.e. i can add images and text also  in runtime.So for that i have taken text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved as follows. Taken Scrollview, in that managing size of the textview & inserting image with Specified size. Like textview,image,tetxview, image and goes on...

Thanks for all your support to solve the issue.

Comment: hi, i also stuck with this thing, haw u done this thing?? plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableView. Put the image in a custom cell with the view as an ImageView.

Put a UITextField as the second cell for text note.

Alternatively, you can use a view swap method, where the text view is on the back of the image by clicking on an "Info" button to use the Flip transition and show the note. The facebook app does this now for "Comments" on photos.

Comment: thanks for replay,
but my requirement is editable.So i can remove image then the below text will add to above text or i can insert multiple images at  time, for that i taken scroll view. above the scroll view i taken first text view, after that if i include image allocated uiimageview then text view again. like that i have done. but when i edit first text view text goes below the image for that i have to adjust frames of all views  after the text view . like this im doing a lengthy process. please suggest me a fine coding for this.
thanks